# Can I send a C++ class object via boost::interprocess::message_queue?

Tags: c++, boost, message-queue

How do I send a c++ class object via `boost::interprocess::message_queue`?

Can someone share sample code for an IPC implementation using `boost::interprocess::message_queue` with IPC data as a Class object?

Answer (score 0):

```
How can i send c++ class object via boost::interprocess::message_queue?

//Class Defination
#define MQ_DATA             IPCMsg
class IPCMsg
{
public:
IPCMsg() { data = NULL; }
int len;
void* data;
};

// Initialize message Queue
mSendMq = new message_queue(OPEN_OR_CREATE, "MQ", 1024, sizeof(MQ_DATA));
mReceiveMq = new message_queue(OPEN_ONLY, "MQ");

// Send Data to message Queue
MQ_DATA* inData = new IPCMsg();
mSendMq->send(inData, sizeof(*inData), 0);

// Receive Data from message Queue
MQ_DATA* outdata = NULL;
mReceiveMq->receive(&outdata, sizeof(*outdata), 1024, priority);
```

Comment: Does this compile?

Comment: Note, that even if this did compile you are passing a raw pointer (uninitialized) -- `inData->data` -- from the address space of one process to the address space of another and expecting it to be valid.

Comment: @G.M , It was compiling successfully. I have shared you the partial code. I was initializing "inData->data" and sending it to Message Queue. But observed, results were not as expected. Could you please help me in this regard by sharing some sample code for better understanding